# Android SQLite error: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an application and using SQLite to save my setting data. But I keep getting this error:
*android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0*

I have tried to insert default value but still getting this error. Maybe there is something that I misunderstood. Here is the file

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AppData.db";

/**
 * table note contain id, title, content
 */
public static final String TABLE_DATA_NAME = "tb_mydata";
public static final String TABLE_SETTING_NAME = "tb_mysetting";
public static final String NOTE_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String NOTE_COLUMN_COLOR = "color";
public static final String NOTE_COLUMN_SENSORID = "sensorid";
public static final String NOTE_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String NOTE_COLUMN_VALUE = "value";
public static final String NOTE_COLUMN_TIME = "time";
public static final String NOTE_SETTING_LOC = "loc";
public static final String NOTE_SETTING_LANG = "lang";
public static final String NOTE_SETTING_SENS = "sensitive";
/**
 * string for create table note
 */
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_DATA_NOTE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DATA_NAME + "(" +
                NOTE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" +
                "," + NOTE_COLUMN_SENSORID + "INTEGER" +
                "," + NOTE_COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                "," + NOTE_COLUMN_VALUE + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                "," + NOTE_COLUMN_TIME + "DATETIME" +
                "," + NOTE_COLUMN_COLOR + "TEXT" +
                ")";
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_SETTING_NOTE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SETTING_NAME + "(" +
                NOTE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" +
                "," + NOTE_SETTING_LANG + "TEXT NOT NULL" +
                "," + NOTE_SETTING_LOC + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                "," + NOTE_SETTING_SENS + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                ")";

/**
 * value for update database
 */
public static final int DATA_VERSION = 1;

/**
 * Sqlite database
 */
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public MySQLHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATA_VERSION);
}

/**
 * create db when app start, and only call when database don't create
 * When database created, it will not call
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DATA_NOTE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SETTING_NOTE);
}

/**
 * call when change DATA_VERSION
 * help we update database
 */
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * open database
 */
public void open() {
    try {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * close database
 */
public void close() {
    if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
        try {
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public Cursor getAll(String sql) {
    open();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    close();
    return cursor;
}


public boolean insertNote(String sensorid, String title, String value, String time, String color) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NOTE_COLUMN_SENSORID,sensorid);
    contentValues.put(NOTE_COLUMN_TITLE, title);
    contentValues.put(NOTE_COLUMN_VALUE, value);
    contentValues.put(NOTE_COLUMN_TIME,time);
    contentValues.put(NOTE_COLUMN_COLOR, color);
    try {
        db.insert(TABLE_DATA_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean insertSettingNote(String lang, String loc, String sens) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NOTE_SETTING_LANG,lang);
    contentValues.put(NOTE_SETTING_LOC, loc);
    contentValues.put(NOTE_SETTING_SENS, sens);
    try {
        db.insert(TABLE_SETTING_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * update values to table
 *
 * @return index row update
 */
public boolean update(String table, ContentValues values, String where) {
    open();
    //values.put();
    long index = db.update(table, values, where, null);
    close();
    return index > 0;
}



/**
 * delete id row of table
 */
public boolean delete(String table, String where) {
    open();
    long index = db.delete(table, where, null);
    close();
    return index > 0;
}

public Note getNote(String sql) {
    Note note = null;
    Cursor cursor = getAll(sql);
    if (cursor != null) {
        note = cursorToNote(cursor);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return note;
}
public SettingNote getSettingNote(String sql) {
    SettingNote stnote = null;
    Cursor cursor = getAll(sql);
    if (cursor != null) {
        stnote = cursorToSettingNote(cursor);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return stnote;
}

/**
 * @param sql get all notes with sql command
 * @return arraylist of note
 */
public ArrayList<Note> getListNote(String sql) {
    ArrayList<Note> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getAll(sql);

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursorToNote(cursor));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    return list;
}

/**
 * insert note to table
 *
 * @param note note to insert
 * @return id of note
 */


/**
 * @param note note to update
 * @return id of note update
 */
public boolean updateNote(Note note) {
    return update(TABLE_DATA_NAME, noteToValues(note), NOTE_COLUMN_ID + " = " + note.getId());
}

/**
 * delete id row of table
 */
public boolean deleteNote(Note note) {
    return delete(TABLE_DATA_NAME, NOTE_COLUMN_ID + " = " + note.getId());
}

/**
 * convert note to contentvalues
 * don't put id of note because
 * when insert id will auto create
 * when update we don't update id
 */
private ContentValues noteToValues(Note note) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NOTE_COLUMN_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    values.put(NOTE_COLUMN_VALUE, note.getValue());
    return values;
}

private ContentValues noteToValues(SettingNote stnote) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NOTE_SETTING_SENS, stnote.getSensitive());
    values.put(NOTE_SETTING_LOC,  stnote.getLoc());
    values.put(NOTE_SETTING_LANG, stnote.getLang());
    return values;
}
/**
 * convert cursor to note
 */
private Note cursorToNote(Cursor cursor) {
    Note note = new Note();
    note.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE_COLUMN_ID)))
            .setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE_COLUMN_TITLE)))
            .setvalue(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE_COLUMN_VALUE)));
    return note;
}

private SettingNote cursorToSettingNote(Cursor cursor) {
    SettingNote Stnote = new SettingNote();
    Stnote.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE_COLUMN_ID)));
    Stnote.setLang(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE_SETTING_LANG)));
    Stnote.setLoc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE_SETTING_LOC)));
    Stnote.setSensitive(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE_SETTING_SENS)));
    return Stnote;
}

public long getProfilesCount(String databasename) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long cnt  = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, databasename);
    db.close();
    return cnt;
}


RadioButton mRGLangEng, mRGLangViet, mRGLocHN, mRGLocDN;
CheckBox Sens;
Locale myLocale;
MySQLHelper sqlHelper;
SettingNote stNote;
Button Save;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_setting, container, false);
    Sens = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.SensCheck);
    mRGLangEng = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Lang_Eng);
    mRGLangViet = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Lang_Vie);
    mRGLocHN = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.locHanoi);
    mRGLocDN = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.locDanang);
    Save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);
    sqlHelper = new MySQLHelper(this.getActivity());
    sqlHelper.getSettingNote(MySQLHelper.TABLE_SETTING_NAME);
    if (stNote.getLang() == "en") {
        mRGLangViet.setChecked(false);
        mRGLangEng.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        mRGLangViet.setChecked(true);
        mRGLangEng.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (stNote.getSensitive() == "no") {
        Sens.setChecked(false);
        Constants.USER_LIMITATION = 200;
    } else {
        Sens.setChecked(true);
        Constants.USER_LIMITATION = 150;
    }
    if (stNote.getLang() == "hn") {
        mRGLocHN.setChecked(true);
        mRGLocDN.setChecked(false);
        Constants.API_TYPE_AQI = 1; // Sensor's ID at HN_RDC
        Constants.API_TYPE_TMP = 2;
        Constants.API_TYPE_HUM = 3;

    } else {
        mRGLocHN.setChecked(false);
        mRGLocDN.setChecked(true);
        Constants.API_TYPE_AQI = 7;
        Constants.API_TYPE_TMP = 8;
        Constants.API_TYPE_HUM = 9;

    }

    mRGLocHN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRGLocDN.setChecked(false);
            Constants.STR_LOC = "hn";
        }
    });

    mRGLocDN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRGLocHN.setChecked(false);
            Constants.STR_LOC = "dn";
        }
    });

    mRGLangViet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRGLangEng.setChecked(false);
            Constants.STR_LANG = "vi";
            setLocale("vi");
        }
    });

    mRGLangEng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRGLangViet.setChecked(false);
            Constants.STR_LANG = "en";
            setLocale("en");
        }
    });

    Sens.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Sens.isChecked()){
                Sens.setChecked(false);
                Constants.STR_SENS = "no";
            }else{
                Sens.setChecked(true);
                Constants.STR_SENS = "yes";
            }
        }
    });

    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(MySQLHelper.NOTE_SETTING_LANG,Constants.STR_LANG);
            cv.put(MySQLHelper.NOTE_SETTING_LOC, Constants.STR_LOC);
            cv.put(MySQLHelper.NOTE_SETTING_SENS, Constants.STR_SENS);
            sqlHelper.update(MySQLHelper.TABLE_SETTING_NAME,cv,"id = 1");
        }
    });


    return view;
}

public void setLocale(String lang) {
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
}
```

And here is the error

```
11-10 21:54:14.487 2174-2174/com.journaldev.viewpager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.journaldev.viewpager, PID: 2174
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
    at com.journaldev.viewpager.MyApplication.MyApp.MySQLHelper.cursorToSettingNote(MySQLHelper.java:270)
    at com.journaldev.viewpager.MyApplication.MyApp.MySQLHelper.getSettingNote(MySQLHelper.java:191)
    at com.journaldev.viewpager.MyApplication.MyApp.TabSetting.onCreateView(TabSetting.java:41)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

11-10 21:54:42.516 2174-2174/com.journaldev.viewpager I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2174 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Not sure about this if causing for exception but there should be space between column name and Datatype `"," + NOTE_COLUMN_SENSORID + "INTEGER" +`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the cursor has value or not and need to move the cursor to the first position before fetching the value which will avoid this issue. One more thing try to use try catch block and in finally block close the cursor, before closing the cursor check whether the cursor is closed or not like below:

```
Cursor cursor = null;

try {

 String selectQuery = "your query";

        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                       //Looping cursor and fetching the value...
                   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
   cursor.close();
   }
}
```

Hope this is helpful:)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
sqlHelper.getSettingNote("select * from "+MySQLHelper.TABLE_SETTING_NAME);
```

Comment: Please review the answer